# Display Images from Database via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to display the images, stored in a table, in PHP Database, table name is "bbmp" and the column containing the images is named as, "image"

Please help me in the code in this matter as it shows my output like this

```
<?php    

include("dbconnection.php");  // it contains all the details of the database name, database host and password 
$y=$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bbmp`";
$result = mysql_query($y);
echo "<table align='center'> <tr> <td> uid </td> <td> username </td> <td> Address </td> <td> email </td> <td> description </td>  <td> status </td> <td> Images </td> </tr>";
if(!$result)
{
    echo "not run ($y) from: ".mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while($pat=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$uid=$pat['uid'];
$username=$pat['username'];
$address=$pat['address'];
$email=$pat['email'];
$description=$pat['description'];
$status=$pat['status'];
$image=$pat['image'];
echo "<tr> <td> $uid </td> <td> $username </td> <td> $address </td> <td> $email </td> <td> $description </td> <td> $status </td> <td> $image </td> </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<html>
<body>
<a href="main.html">Go Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

All the field is viewed except image. It shows image in some uni-code. Please help

Comment: what is the `$image` variable holding in it? imagename? imagepath? binary code of the image?

Answer (score 0):

i dont see your output, i hope this will help you..

if your image column contains image path, you must write

```
  <img src="$image">
```

but

your column contains image as binary you can write

```
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,$image">
```

if your image data is base64 encoded

also, if your image saved binary data, you can show it like below;

```
    <img src="image.php?data=xxxxx">
```

your image.php header must be image/jpg etc...